# Octobercms: clear $attachOne relationship

Tags: php, activerecord, zurb-foundation, relationship, octobercms

I have a problem updating an *attachOne* relation of a model from a frontend form under **Octobercms**.

I have a "*Customer*" model and relative controller with a field in the backend form where I, as admin, can edit its company logo.

I also have built (with **Foundation**) a frontend form that the logged in customer can edit, changing his logo accordingly.

I setup a *placeholder* in my

```
/themes/mytheme/dist/assets/img/placeholder.png
```

and I show it when the user hasn't uploaded his file yet.

I can then upload a pic and change the logo correctly and I set the

```
$model->company_logo
```

with no issues.

The problem is when the user resets the form and submits a **null** field value: I'm not able to empty the $model->company_logo relation.

I tried with *unset()*, passing *null* values, *empty strings* and so on but with no luck.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I feel so newbie.

I just put this in my frontend form page php section:

```
function onSave() {
    // ... 
    $uploadedLogo = \Input::file('company_logo');

    if (empty($uploadedLogo)) {
        $customer->company_logo->delete();
    } else {
        $customer->company_logo = $uploadedLogo;
    }
    // ...
}
```